# Thunderbird: possible to change selected email highlight color (when no focus)?

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to change, in the message list of Thunderbird 3.0, the highlight color of the selected message  *when the list does not have the focus*?

The highlight color for the selected row is blue when the list has the focus, this is very clear. But when the list does not have the focus (e.g. after when you click in the message preview area), the highlight color is dark grey. However, this dark grey doesn't really stand out against the alternating row highlighting in the list (at least not on my laptop's LCD screen), making it difficult for me to quickly locate the message I've selected.

So, any way to change this *dark grey highlighting*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to change the color of the selected row in thunderbird

create a file named

**userChrome.css**

in the directory

**%Appdata%\Thunderbird\Profiles\ {profile_dir} \chrome**

with following content (replace #FFD445 and #000000 with your favored color):

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#threadTree treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
background-color: #FFD445 !important;
}

#threadTree treechildren:-moz-tree-cell-text(selected) {
color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Ditto - I was about to put a bounty on this but found it was already answered. Worked perfectly and just reduced my heartburn too. Thanks.

Comment: Works with TB 3 too. For the tree of folders itself, it must be `#folderTree`. And you might need to add `-moz-appearance: none !important;` to override the existing style (eg. background-image). If focus color must be changed too, must duplicate the above with `(selected, focus)`

Comment: Not surprising but it no longer works, just tried in TB 115.