# Thunderbird 78.0: possible to change selected email highlight color (when no focus)?

Tags: thunderbird, user-interface

recently thunderbird 78.0 change a big way its UI.

Although the changes are mostly good ones, I find that it is much less easy to see what element is selected (for example is the focus on the folders pane or on the mails pane ? no one knows !)

So I'd like to change the color of the selected element.

I found this post in my research : [Thunderbird: possible to change selected email highlight color (when no focus)?](https://superuser.com/questions/133594/thunderbird-possible-to-change-selected-email-highlight-color-when-no-focus), but it seems that this information is way out of date (which makes sense, since the question was asked 11 years ago).

Does anyone know what would be the modern equivalent to the post aforementioned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the CSS I have currently in Thunderbird; the `(selected)`  rules cause items that are simultaneously selected and unfocused to be highlighted in yellow with black text:

```
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected) {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color: black !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected, focus) {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
    color: white !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
    border: none !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected, focus) {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
}
```

Note that my CSS has no `@namespace` declaration or `#threadTree` selectors as shown in the old post.

Also, `Highlight` is the system highlight color normally used when selecting items. If that doesn't work for some reason or if you want to use a different color than the system highlight for focused selected items, `Highlight` can be replaced with whatever color you want.

While my current Thunderbird version is 78.11.0, I've been using this same CSS since before version 78.0 (except I normally use `lightgray` rather than `yellow`).

**Important note:** (from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1298376#question-reply) If you are using a more recent version of Thunderbird and you've never created a userChrome.css file for your profile before, you'll need to enable the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` setting in Config Editor.

***Update for Thunderbird 115+***

Thunderbird 115 "Supernova" seems to have metaphorically blown up CSS support, so a lot of customization will probably need to be rewritten. Haven't run into problems myself yet since I'm on Fedora Linux 37 with TB 102 similar to Mark Morgan Lloyd. But I installed TB 115 on a Win10 machine and sussed out the following example using the built-in Developer Toolbox. It should provide basically the same colors as the previous CSS except for unselected items' background being green (#80F880) just to make the coloring more obvious.

```
table.tree-table tbody[is="tree-view-table-body"] tr {
    background-color: #80F880 !important;
    color: black !important;
}

table.tree-table tbody[is="tree-view-table-body"] tr.selected {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    color: black !important;
}

table.tree-table tbody[is="tree-view-table-body"]:focus tr.selected {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

While it appears to work, it's probably not optimal. Someone may be able to come up with more concise selectors.

Comment: Great ! Do you know where I'm supposed to create this userChrome.css on Linux ?

Comment: For those who, like me, do this for the first time on linux : create the `chrome` folder in `~/.thunderbird` if it does not exist, then create the `chromeUser.css` file inside it, simply add your css code in this file, restart thunderbird, and done !
I ended up only using
```css
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected, focus) { 
background-color: Highlight !important;
}
```
But it's great ! thanks :D

Comment: Doesn't work in TB 115.

Comment: @GringoSuave Updated answer for TB 115.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to say that David Yockey's answer is still good with TB 102 in mid-'23.

To get a message listing reminiscent of "music-ruled" paper with sensible highlighting, I'm using

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

/* Background color CSS for mail list */
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(odd) {

 border: 1px solid transparent !important;
 background-color: #FFFFCC !important;
 min-height: 18px !important;
 height: 1.3em !important;

}

treechildren::-moz-tree-row(even) {

 border: 1px solid transparent !important;
 background-color: #CCFFCC !important;
 min-height: 18px !important;
 height: 1.3em !important;

}

/* Colours with reference to http://www.ficml.org/jemimap/style/color/wheel.html MarkMLl */

/* Special cases for selected messages etc. See https://superuser.com/questions/1658114/thunderbird-78-0-possible-to-change-sele

treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}

treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected, focus) {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in TB 115.

Comment: @GringoSuave do you have a fix? :-)

Comment: Tried a few things from here and search.  Didn't find a solution.  Found a FAQ which boils down to "we hardcoded it."  :-P
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-115-supernova-faq

Comment: @GringoSuave Thanks for the link. I don't have the latest version yet since I use Debian Linux which is "conservative" and sitting on 102. I had to work through a very large email messagebase over the Summer, and to be honest this change sounds like the sort of thing that would resulted in my bringing up an older version in a container. Yet another example of traditional technology being "dumbed down"...

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Updated answer for TB 115.

Comment: @DavidYockey Thanks for the extra work :-)